# How to open php popup message on localhost computer screen via mobile phone connection?

Tags: php, mobile, localhost

There is apache server installed on my localhost computer (win7 system) with php. c:\apache is my localhost directory. I can connect to localhost with my mobile phone. I can reach the content of the localhost folder and run PHP files.

**I want to send a popup message to localhost computer screen via mobile phone connection.**

I tried to use a vbs script in php file and tried the following functions :

vbs file content
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WScript.Quit (WshShell.Popup( "My message here" ,10 ,"Warning", 64+4096))

```
exec("message.vbs");
shell_exec("message.vbs")
system("message.vbs)
exec("start message.vbs")
exec("start warning.wav")  // It can be a sound message instead of text msg
```

VBS script works when I run it directly on the local computer but I can't run it from PHP file.

I hope it is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this?

```
exec('cmd %pathToVBSFile%');
```

I found this on php.net:

```
 start MSPaint maximized and wait for you to close it before continuing the script: 

<?php 
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell"); 
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("mspaint.exe", 3, true); 
?>
```

Did you tried to execute something else than VBS from PHP?
You can try to convert the vbScript to a .exe with *Vbs to  Exe* (maybe apache doesn't have the right to execute VBS)

Comment: exec('cmd %pathToVBSFile%'); doesn't work.  And I converted vbs to exe just now. exec("warning.exe") didn't work too. Actually, I can't run any exe from exec(), I can't even run exec("notepad.exe");  php.net script causes error.

Comment: How did you write it?
Is the VBS file in the same folder as the php that try to execute it?

Comment: warning.vbs in the same folder. It works when I click it directly, I mean clicking the vbs file itself on the local computer.  I tried to run it from php file  exec("message.vbs") and I converted it to exe then tried exec("message.exe").

Comment: If you put the vbs file in the root folder (a example of the folder tree would be helpfull here)

Comment: To summerize, there is a localhost computer with apache server. My aim is to send a popup msg or play a wav file on the localhost computer screen via mobile connection.

Comment: Folder content (http:\\localhost                                                                          c:\apache\warning.vbs     c:\apache\test.php    exec("warning.vbs")

Comment: I know but where did your php file is locate? It may be a wrong path (your current directory seem to point to another folder)
To know the current directory, use<< dirname(__FILE__);>>

Comment: The files are in the same folder so it should work.
Remember that a apache server on Windows don't react the same as apache server on ubuntu for example. I would  try to put the complete path to be sure.

Comment: The localhost url is http:\\localhost   and  it is c:\apache.  When I write this url,  the content of c:\apache  appears. I use the localhost for web desing, it works.

Comment: Ok so it look like a permission issue.
Do you have some warning or error in the event viewer?

Comment: No error messages. Only blank screen.  I want to run exe from mobile but I can't even run any exe files on localhost computer itself. http:\\localhost\test.php.

Comment: Event viewer is a Windows tool: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766401(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

*I want to send a popup message to localhost computer screen via mobile phone connection.*
Win 7-8's msg.exe don't display popup message. I did it with windows XP msg.exe. I carried xp's msg.exe to win 7-8's system32 folder. It worked.
I added the following code to my php file test.php. And when I run it from mobile phone, it sends a popup message on localhost computer screen.

```
http://192.168.1.102/test.php



<? msg username hello world ?>
```